# Multiple for_each loops in a single terraform resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, foreach, terraform, aws-lake-formation

I have a lake formation permissions resource in which I am looping through users in a iam group and assigning permissions. As for the database name , this is more than 1 database. Is it possible to have a second `for_each` statement within the database object or will I need to do something else instead ?

```
resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "admin-lf-permissions" {
  for_each = { for usr in data.aws_iam_group.admin.users: usr.user_name => usr.arn }
  principal   = each.value
  permissions = ["ALL"]

  database {
    name       = data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name
   
  }
}
```

I have the following inside my l`ocals.tf` which is what I want to ideally loop through. So for example , admin users will have access to all the databases that are specified within map `admin_dbs`

```
glue_catalog_dbs = {

    admin_dbs= {
     db-1                  =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.prod-database
      db-2            =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.test-database
     db-3           =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.dev-database
    },

    data_engineer_dbs= {
       db-1                  =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.prod-database
      db-2            =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.test-database
     db-3           =   data.terraform_remote_state.glue_catalog_database.outputs.map_glue_catalog_db_name.dev-database
    }
```

I have looked through using the for loop but am unsure if that is the way forward OR if i can make use of a second for_each loop

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple `for_each` [meta arguments](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) in a Terraform resource block. You should create a single, combined list of all the permissions that need to be created, and pass that to the `for_each` argument.

Comment: I am making use of a data source to obtain a list of iam users. As for the database , I am not sure how to loop through what I have in my locals.tf

Comment: I'm not sure how to loop through what you have in locals.tf either. I would suggest refactoring your locals.tf to match what you actually can use easily in your resources.